# Function to test if snake has collided with itself won't work

Tags: javascript

Hey everyone I'm making a snake game in JS. Right Now I'm working on the function that will stop the game if the snake head has hit somewhere on the snake body. since the snakes an array, I loop through every snake unit and compare it with the head unit. The problem is now the game stops before you can even start. Since the snake head is in the array that's being looped through the very first loop compares the head position with itself and since there both at the same position the game stops. Any ideas?

```js
//declare global variables
const canvas = document.querySelector('#canvas');

//set canvas context
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

//put canvas dimensions into variables
const cvsW = canvas.width;
const cvsH = canvas.height;

//create snake unit
const unit = 16;

//create snake and set starting position
let snake = [{
 x : cvsW/2,
 y : cvsH/2
}]

//create food object and set its position somewhere on board
let food = {
 //Math.floor(Math.random()*cvsW + 1)---number from 1 to 784
 //Math.floor(Math.random()*cvsW/unit + 1)---number from 1 to 79
 //Math.floor(Math.random()*cvsW/unit + 1)*unit---number from 1 to 784(but it's a multiple of unit)
 //Math.floor(Math.random()*(cvsW/unit - 1)+1)*unit---same as above but -1 keeps food inside canvas
 x : Math.floor(Math.random()*(cvsW/unit - 1)+1)*unit-unit/2,
 y : Math.floor(Math.random()*(cvsH/unit - 1)+1)*unit-unit/2
}

//create a variable to store the direction of the snake
let direction;

//add event to read users input then change direction
document.addEventListener('keydown', (e) => {
 if(e.keyCode == 37 && direction != 'right') direction = 'left';
 else if (e.keyCode == 38 && direction != 'down') direction = 'up';
 else if (e.keyCode == 39 && direction != 'left') direction = 'right';
 else if (e.keyCode == 40 && direction != 'up') direction = 'down';
})

function draw() {
 //clear canvas and redraw snake 
 ctx.clearRect(0, 0, cvsW, cvsH);
 for(let i = 0; i < snake.length; i++) {
  ctx.fillStyle = 'limegreen';
  ctx.fillRect(snake[i].x-unit/2, snake[i].y-unit/2, unit, unit);
 }
 //draw food
 ctx.fillStyle = 'red';
 ctx.fillRect(food.x-unit/2, food.y-unit/2, unit, unit);

 //grab heads position
 let headX = snake[0].x;
 let headY = snake[0].y;

 //move snake in chosen direction
 if(direction == 'left') headX -= unit;
 else if(direction == 'right') headX += unit;
 else if(direction == 'up') headY -= unit;
 else if(direction == 'down') headY += unit;

 //create new snake unit
 let newHead = {x : headX, y :headY}

 //check to see if snakes eaten food
 if(headX === food.x && headY === food.y) {
  food = {
   x : Math.floor(Math.random()*(cvsW/unit - 1)+1)*unit-unit/2,
   y : Math.floor(Math.random()*(cvsH/unit - 1)+1)*unit-unit/2
  }
  //create 4 new units
  for(let i = 4; i > 0; i--) {
   //add those units -without this code snake will not grow 
   snake.unshift(newHead);
  }
 } else {
  //remove tail -without this code snake will keep growing
  snake.pop();
 }
 //add new head position -without this code snake will not move
 snake.unshift(newHead);

 //check to see if snake has hit a wall or itself
 if(headX < 0 || headX > cvsW || headY < 0 || headY > cvsH || collision(headX, headY)) {
  clearInterval(runGame);
 }
}

let runGame = setInterval(draw, 70);

function collision(x, y) {
 for(let i = 0; i < snake.length; i++) {
  if(x == snake[i].x && y == snake[i].y) return true;
 }
 return false;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Snake Game</title>
 <style>
  body {
   background-color: #333;
  }

  canvas {
   background-color: #4d4d4d;
   margin: auto;
   display: block;
   position: absolute;
   left: 0;
   right: 0;
   top: 0;
   bottom: 0;
   width: 750px;
   height: 500px;  
  }
 </style>
</head>
<body>
 <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
 <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add collision script to ignore the first two links of the snake when checking collisions with itself.

```
function selfcollision(x, y) {
    for(let i = 2; i < snake.length; i++) {
        if(x == snake[i].x && y == snake[i].y) return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: I've tried this, this makes the snake move yes, but now when I hit a food unit the game stops?

Comment: Your use of `snake.unshift(newhead)` is adding the same value for head four times at the beginning of the array.  Remove the loop.Store the targetlength for the snake at initialization. Increment targetlength by four when food collision.  Do not call `snake.pop()` if the size of the array is < targetlength.